# How to enable xml autocompletion for liquibase changesets in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, liquibase

I need a schema file or something. Where can I get it for liquibase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the Liquibase XSD. There are several versions. The documentation lists some of them here:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/xml_format.html

The latest version available is 3.5, which is at http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd

Comment: I put that xsd to %InstallRoot%\Xml\Schemas but it looks like the schema is still not used when I open changelog.xml. Why?

Comment: That is a question more for the Visual Studio folks I think. I googled "how to get visual studio to use xsd" and got some promising results. I don't have Visual Studio, so I can't tell if they will work or not.